# What's the best way to copy a millions rows from one sql server database to another?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have one database that gets a million rows added to it on a daily basis. Every day I'd like to run a query to pull out the million oldest rows(leaving about ten million in the database), and then move them into an archive database.

There are well documented ways of doing this with sql server(bcp, openrowset, etc), but from what I can tell, all of those methods take all of the rows from a data file. I only want to copy a subset of the rows, and I can't find any quick ways of doing that.

Comment: Are they on different servers or the same server?  Also, do you want to delete the data from the source as well?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest considering an SSIS package. You can control exactly what rows get copied, you can do it in transaction sizes of your choice, and it will do a fast bulk insert.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is with a query which uses fully qualified names

```
INSERT INTO ArchiveDatabase..TableName 
SELECT * 
FROM ProductionDatabase..TableName
WHERE EntryDate <= dateadd(mm, -6, current_timestamp)
```

To copy over large volumes of data it is often better to do this "chunk based". The easiest way to do this in pure TSQL is like this:

```
DECLARE @rowcount int
  SET @rowcount = 1
  WHILE @rowcount <> 0
    BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO ArchiveDatabase..TableName 
      SELECT TOP (100000) * 
      FROM ProductionDatabase..TableName
      WHERE EntryDate <= dateadd(mm, -6, current_timestamp) 
      SET @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    END
```

Basically limit the query to 100k rows with the `SELECT TOP()` clause and keep looping until no more records are copied over. (`@@ROWCOUNT` returns the number of affected records.)

If the databases are located on different SQL Servers you can set up a "Linked Server" and add the server reference to the object name. The format of a fully qualified object name is `<Server>.<Database>.<Owner>.<Object>`